# LocalStorage vs Sqlite database

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I have a hybrid application which runs on Android and ios platform, I have  been using "localStorage" as data storage.

I also heard sqlite as well, Is there any other local database that I can use for mobile storage?

I would like to know prop and cons in these technologies.

I would really appreciate if anyone can clarify about these technologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage data or storage in Android by following ways,

1. Shared Preferences
2. Internal Storage
3. External Storage
4. SQLite Databases
5. Network Connection

You can manage the storage or data in iOS by following ways,

1. Property lists
2. SQLite database
3. Core Data

As you say that you have a hybrid application which is for Android and ios you should use SQLite database, because

1. It is light weight
2. Comfortable with both Android and iOS [ Cross platform ]
3. capacity to Handle huge data
4. The handling of code, manipulating the code is much easy with sqlite.

So, its my opinion to u that you should use SQLite as an database for hybrid application, it will be easy for you. If you are doing application only for iOS then core date can be another good option since you doing both one SQLite is best.

Answer (score 1):

As far as we consider speed and performance , SQLITE is best according to docs.
but you can use xml data storage as well but you will find a little bit slow than sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited. Shared Preferences, local storage, sqlite and network are your only options.

Everything you need to know about your options can be found at the [official Storeage Options docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

I recommend that if you only need to save user options and states and not lots of data then you only need to use Shared Preferences. You can even save JSON in the shared preferences if you don't want to setup a sqlite database.

And remember a user can wipe app data from the app settings, if your worried about the data being wiped then the only option is network or a combination with network.